# performance test using curl - delays

Tags: performance, curl, web, delay

Can somebody help in analysis of the below output received when testing perfomance of certain website? Especially those lines representing progress meter

It appears to me `curl` re-tries downloading the content of the page a couple of times.. am I right ?

What would be the possible causes - would it be the malformed Content-Lenght response header ?

---

```
About to connect() to xx.example.com port 80 (#0)
Trying 12.12.12.12... connected
Connected to xx.example.com (12.12.12.12) port 80 (#0)
GET /testing/page HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:2.0.1)
            Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Host: mp.example.com
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK

 Age: 26        
 Date: Thu, 21 Sept 2012 15:19:48 GMT
 Cache-Control: max-age=60        
 Xontent-Length:           
 Connection: Close     
 Via: proxy
 ETag: "KNANXUSNFMBN"
 Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
 Vary: Accept-Encoding

[data not shown]
```

```
100 32074    0 32074    0     0  54987      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 55300
100 49400    0 49400    0     0  28372      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:-- 28423
100 52121    0 52121    0     0  20174      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:-- 20201
100 58912    0 58912    0     0  16923      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:-- 16938
```

```
100 58912    0 58912    0     0  13142      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:-- 13152
100 58912    0 58912    0     0  10742      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--  5476
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   9083      0 --:--:--  0:00:06 --:--:--  2004
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   7868      0 --:--:--  0:00:07 --:--:--  1384
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   6940      0 --:--:--  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   6207      0 --:--:--  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   5615      0 --:--:--  0:00:10 --:--:--     0
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   5125      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   4715      0 --:--:--  0:00:12 --:--:--     0
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   4365      0 --:--:--  0:00:13 --:--:--     0
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   4063      0 --:--:--  0:00:14 --:--:--     0
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   3801      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:--     0
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   3570      0 --:--:--  0:00:16 --:--:--     0
100 58912    0 58912    0     0   3366      0 --:--:--  0:00:17 --:--:--     0
100 58913    0 58913    0     0   3226      0 --:--:--  0:00:18 --:--:--     0
100  113k    0  113k    0     0   6067      0 --:--:--  0:00:19 --:--:-- 12387*
Closing connection #0

END - total_time: 19.094
(cumul_times - dns: 0.002 connect: 0.004 pretrans: 0.004 firstbyte: 0.006)
status: 200 size: 115856 hsize: 269 date: 16.08.2012-18:20:33 1345130433
```

---

I would appreciate all input on this.

I am troubleshooting the delays to that specific web page, I am looking for advise on how to interpret those curl progress meter lines.
in working scenario - where there is no delay - there is 1 progress meter line :

```
Age: 28        
Date: Thu, 21 Sep Aug 2012 15:20:46 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=60        
Content-Length: 115856    
Connection: Keep-Alive
Via: proxy
ETag: "KXNFGAHSKCUY"
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
[data not shown]

100  113k  100  113k    0     0  6402k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 8703k*
Connection #0 to host xx.example.com left intact

Closing connection #0
END - **total_time: 0.018**
(cumul_times - dns: 0.002 connect: 0.004 pretrans: 0.004 firstbyte: 0.006)
status: 200 size: 115856 hsize: 269 date: 16.08.2012-18:21:14 1345130474
```

My question is what do the individual lines mean? That the curl got only part of the content and has been re-trying and re-trying.
And what could be the cause? Slow server? Drops on the WAN connection .....?

Comment: Whats wrong with those bold lines? I see these are curl progress bar messages which is supposed to `\r` ended. They are not `\n` ended. So individual lines dont matter.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the curl request you executed?
Though, You may want to use `ab` or `apib` (available on google code) for benchmarking.

Comment: have added some more info into my summary